# /lib/ld-linux.so.2: No such file or directory

Tags: qt5

In an attempt to install `Qt5` in `Ubuntu-mate18.04`, `raspberrypi3b+` I get the following error. Please check the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have the `binutils` package installed. This provides the `ld` linker program and the lib you are missing.