# bash: No such file or directory (for 32-bit binary on Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, elf

I am trying to run an older, 32-bit binary on Ubuntu 20.04 on an x86_64 machine. Here is the profile of the binary from `file`:

```
$ file /usr/local/diamond/3.13/modeltech/linuxloem/vsim
/usr/local/diamond/3.13/modeltech/linuxloem/vsim: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=b8557f9eb74b21146d0eba49769f30f475422d26, stripped
```

When I execute the binary, I get this error:

```
$ /usr/local/diamond/3.13/modeltech/linuxloem/vsim
bash: /usr/local/diamond/3.13/modeltech/linuxloem/vsim: No such file or directory
```

I cannot figure out what the problem is.  Permissions on the binary are fine (`mwg` is my user and group):

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/diamond/3.13/modeltech/linuxloem/vsim
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mwg mwg 7772676 Jul 18  2023 /usr/local/diamond/3.13/modeltech/linuxloem/vsim
```

The same problem occurs when trying to run the binary as root (i.e., prefixing the command with `sudo`).

The only thing I can think of is that this binary is expecting an interpreter at `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` (from the `file` output above), and this path does not exist on my system.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57093081/lib-ld-linux-so-2-no-such-file-or-directory) gave me the idea that I may need to `apt install binutils`, but I tried that, and it did not fix the problem.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can run this binary?  Or how to further diagnose the problem?

Comment: Yes, the interpreter being missing is _exactly_ the problem. I'm not sure it's on topic here, though -- this is more a system configuration issue than a software development issue, and thus better fit to [UNIX.se] or [ubuntu.se]

Comment: it's not clear how you researched the issue so fwiw ... a web search on `ubuntu AND "32-bit" AND "No such file or directory"` brings up quite a few hits; [first one I picked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389) has a few answers that look promising

Comment: @markp-fuso Thank you; your comment and the answer below moved me forward in getting this binary to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Ubuntu 22.04.4 system, `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` is a symlink to `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2`. That file is provided by the `libc6:i386` package.

Installing `libc6:i386` will likely correct the problem.

```
$ ls -l /lib/ld-linux.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Jan  2 05:22 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -> i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2
$ ls -l /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 225864 Jan  2 05:22 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2
$ dpkg -S /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2
libc6:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2
$
```